# Which one is correct: Most big change or most big changes

Tags: word-usage

I was watching [A Conversation with Barack Obama, Bill Gates and Melinda Gates](https://youtu.be/9buDC32fKw0?t=28) today, and when Barack Obama begins to talk, he says:

> Most big change, most human progress, is driven by...

I am not a native English speaker, but I have a feeling that it should be *most big changes* instead of *most big change*.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with countable and uncountable nouns. [This](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns) link will explain in more detail. In brief, countable things can be counted. Uncountable nouns are also called "mass nouns". Some nouns are countable ("I have three **cats** and one **dog**, I wish I had fewer cats"). Some nouns are uncountable ("I wiped some **dust** off the table" or "We made some **progress**"). Some nouns can be both ("I bought some **coffee**.", "Could you get me a **coffee**?").

The word "change" can be countable ("I made about a dozen changes to the document") or uncountable ("There was little change between drafts of the document"). In your original quote, it is uncountable, and reflects "progress" which is also uncountable.

Comment: The question implies that "changes" is commonly  understood as an uncountable pluraletantum. Fitting a grammatical description a posteriori does not answer the question at all. Phrases like "we want change" sound almost ungrammatical to me. One poblem I see is that *many small changes* making *one big change*, or just *big change* would be counterintuitive, going from plural to singular.

Comment: @vectory, "You must be the change you wish to see in the world"! Feel free to add your own answer. You could say similar things about the word "power", so maybe this is a new question in its own right.

Answer (score -1):

Wiktionary has a quotation, listed under *countable*,

> Of all the transitions brought about on the Earth’s surface by temperature change, ...

With politics, the closest idiom would be *political change*, a *change of politics*. I don't know what *big change* is, in comparison. *a big change* would be countable, *big change* isn't.

The above example could read instead: "by the Earth surface temperature change". This is a bit too unwieldy, hence it may be broken up: "on the Earth's surface by *its* temperature change". Leave out *its* and the meaning remains the same, but the meaning would change if a plural *-es* is added, because it might imply up and down swings, if a single change is single directional..